# Help identifying Adaptec SCSI controller

Tags: raid

Through damn right stupidity I bent the pins on a CPU in a machine have rendering it pretty useless.  In an attempt to reclaim any useful (re-sellable) parts I have removed the Adaptec SCSI controller, however I'm having trouble identifying it and I don't easily have to hand another box to pop it in.
It is labelled as adaptec 3000s it has 4 LVD connectors two internal and two external, the processor is labelled AIC-7899G.
It was controlling a RAID array.
It has space for two memory slots (one of them being filled).
It has a further PCI 64
Does anyone know which part it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptec's KB answers this question:

http://ask.adaptec.com/scripts/adaptec_tic.cfg/php.exe/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=15256&p_created=1199921508&p_topview=1

Adaptec 3000S is just the label of the PCB. This PCB is used with two different controllers:

- Adaptec SCSI RAID 3200S (two Ultra160 SCSI channels, two internal and two external connectors)
- Adaptec SCSI RAID 3400S (four Ultra160 SCSI channels, two internal and four external connectors)

So you're looking for the Adaptec SCSI RAID 3200S

http://www.adaptec.com/en-US/support/raid/scsi_raid/ASR-3200S/